# How is this module for suppressing Forms Authentication supposed to work?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, forms-authentication

[Here's a post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) about a module for suppressing Forms Authentication for certain requests. The idea is that the module is registered in web.config and so for each request it's `Init()` is invoked:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    context.PostReleaseRequestState += OnPostReleaseRequestState;
    context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
}
```

then once the request is nearing the end of the IIS pipeline, `EndRequest` event fires and so this code is invoked:

```
private void OnEndRequest(object source, EventArgs args) {
    var context = (HttpApplication)source;
    var response = context.Response;

    if (context.Context.Items.Contains(SuppressAuthenticationKey)) {
      response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
      response.ClearContent();
      response.StatusCode = 401;
      response.RedirectLocation = null;
    }
}
```

other pieces of the code are invoked earlier and guarantee that `SuppressAuthenticationKey` is set in `context.Context.Items`.

Now I've got IIS sources (they are available for research) and there's the implementation of `FormsAuthenticationModule` and it subscribes to `EndRequest` and the handler for that request dutifully redirects all requests that ended with HTTP 401 code.

Not only I see the code but also I see it working this way. No amount of `.RedirectLocation = null` has any effect on this.

How is that code supposed to suppress Forms Authentication redirect if the redirect is made insuppressible in IIS?

Comment: I'd not ran into this particular issue before - very interesting though. Not entirely sure if this is useful or helps but have found this property which alludes to suppression being allowed/available/possible/desirable in certain situations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect.aspx Which version of the IIS sources are you reviewing, perhaps its only been supported in IIS 7.5 or 8 though Im just guessing?

Comment: @bUKaneer: The property you mention appeared starting with .NET4.5 and I'm reviewing version 4, so it's not yet available.

Comment: @bUKaneer: Mystery resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is how this thing is supposed to work.

`EndRequest` first fires for FormsAuthenticationModule and its event handers sets up a redirect, but the redirect is not performed immediately, the actual effect is that it just sets aside the HTTP 302 and the redirect URL in the response, the request handling continues. Then `EndRequest` fires for the suppression module and the suppression module clears the previously set up redirect as if that never was set up.

So the request handling continues as if there was no redirect in the first place.